# Azure CosmosDb count consumes a lot of RU/s

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using CosmosDb and have a problem where my application is consuming a lot of RU/s. To try and figure things out I have been testing different queries through mongo shell and noticed the following.

When I get all docs in one collection with the following query:

```
db.Article.find({"TenantId":new BinData(3,"quATe8dai0y4t/FycPd4RA==")}).toArray()
```

The Request Charge showed in Azure Portal is higher (as expected) than with this count query:

```
db.Article.count({"TenantId":new BinData(3, "quATe8dai0y4t/FycPd4RA==")})
```

But the Max consumed RU/s is a lot higher for the count query (See diagrams). This surprises me. Shouldn't the Max consumed RU/s be higher for the get since it has a higher Request Charge?

*The collection consists of 6k docs around 600b each.*

[Request Charge Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejZR9.png)

[Max consumed RU/s Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqUSE.png)

Comment: Your screen shots look identical, with just different lines drawn. Did you grab the wrong screen shot for max consumed RU/s? Your screenshot shows lower costs for the get vs the count for both.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It's fixed now.

Comment: On the 2nd diagram Max consumed RU is per partition, while on the first one seems that it counts across all partitions

Comment: Yes that is correct. But the dB only have one partion.

Comment: @OlaPopp did you ever find a solution to this?